# I am looking for an example of DataColumnsWithJoins usage?

Tags: android

I am looking for an example of [DataColumnsWithJoins](http://d.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumnsWithJoins.html) usage? Do you know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, this is only an interface, not a class.  An example class that uses it is ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.  [Here is an example](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/) of using this class.

Comment: Thanks, if you happen to know these classes so well, maybe you can help on this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482631/how-to-get-contacts-in-order-of-they-upcoming-birthdays